Why am I getting an “Access Denied” error for an external hard drive folder?
I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried multiple solutions and none worked.
I am trying to access a folder [Local Disk] on my external hard drive, but it says Access Denied.

I made this folder on my old laptop about three years ago. Later, I moved it to an external hard drive, and it's been working fine since then, until suddenly displaying that error. I've made no changes to my laptop, administrator settings, or anything else.
I tried using TakeOwn and safety mood, but it did not work

I attempted to access the folder using a different laptop and when opening directory Local Disk, it displayed a message that I don't recall. I clicked Continue and it opened normally; however, the subfolders and files within it still show an Access Denied error.

I retried using TakeOwn and icacls, but didn't work
I attempted to change the folder's security settings by adding Everyone, but that didn't work either

Screenshots: 




Have you tried cacls or icacls from and elevated cmd prompt?

Nope, please elaborate more.  Also, here is an update: I attempted to access the folder using a different laptop. When I tried to open the main folder named "Local Disk," it displayed a message that I don't recall. I clicked "continue," and it opened normally. However, the subfolders and files within it still show an "Access Denied" error. I retried using the TAKEOWN and ICACLS commands, but didn't work. I also attempted to change the folder's security settings by adding "Everyone," but that didn't work either.

You need to take ownership of the root of the drive [E:], applying it recursively (e.g. click "Change" on the "Advanced Security Settings" GUI), then once that is done processing (could take hours depending on the amount of files on the drive), you'd add your user with Full control permissions, and the same for System, Administrators, and Everyone (if not wanting the drive tied to your specific user), ensuring all are inherited permissions

I tried to take ownership through Advanced Security Settings and CMD Takeown & ICACLS but only worked for the main file named "Local Disk" while subfolders and files within it still show the same "Access Denied" error.  @JW0914

@Ehabsalama Open an Admin terminal: WinKey+R → Open: cmd → Ctrl+Shift+OK → TakeOwn /F E:\ /R → icacls E:\ /c /t /Grant:r %UserName%:(OI)(CI)F /Grant:r System:(OI)(CI)F /Grant:r Administrators:(OI)(CI)F /Inheritance:e (this must be done in cmd, as powershell will error out from the parentheses in the inheritance rights; cmd /c will not work for this in powershell).  If those two commands do not work to restore access, please add the output of the following to a code box within your question: icacls E:
